# Not sure what this plant is... Anyone?

Tags: identification

It has reddish green leaves.. And long stems that protrude above the leaf area with little seeds or flower buds on the end.. It pretty much looks like this year round in a northern climate (Indiana) It does get browner in the winter.. This picture was taken moments ago in August.. The entire plant is only about 18 inches high. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Palace Purple Heuchera - one that's in more shade than it likes, which is why the leaves are much greener than they should be (OTOH, when I was in the trade, we'd run across brown-leaved and mostly green-leaved "Palace Purple" cultivars. It seems the original cultivar may be lost). The purple undersides to the leaves are one ID marker, and the size and flowers are both correct; the flowers aren't as tight as they should be if this were a tiarella. Tiarellas also tend to bloom in late spring, not mid to late summer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be Tiarella cordifolia, also known as foamflower; although the leaves on yours look a bit soft and droopy, they are the right shape for Tiarella . It's a woodland plant, preferring shady, damp conditions, and the leaves may wilt or droop in sunlight - they turn reddish tones in autumn or if the soil is dry. These days there are many varieties and hybrids - there's even a cross between Tiarella and Heuchera which is sold as Heucherella. https://www.claireaustin-hardyplants.co.uk/products/tiarella-cordifolia